# How to mix queue-based and feed-based input in TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I've recently migrated to a fully_connected style model that reads inputs from a queue generated from a TFRecords file. This has proven much more efficient, but I still would like to pass parameters interactively with placeholder/feed_dict.

Is there a way to use the same computation graph (say you have a model class that builds a graph in the init method) for both a feed_dict and full_connected functionality? Can you get a placeholder to receive values from a dequeue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply feed the output of the dequeue operation. TensorFlow would not actually dequeue any item, it would just use the value you provided. For example:

```
q = tf.FIFOQueue(capacity=10, dtypes=[tf.float32], shapes=[()])
v = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
enqueue = q.enqueue([v])
dequeue = q.dequeue()
output = dequeue + 10.0

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(enqueue, feed_dict={v: 1.0})
    sess.run(enqueue, feed_dict={v: 2.0})
    sess.run(enqueue, feed_dict={v: 3.0})
    print(sess.run(output)) # 11.0
    print(sess.run(output, feed_dict={dequeue: 5.0})) # 15.0
    print(sess.run(output)) # 12.0
    print(sess.run(output)) # 13.0
```

Comment: Wait that's interesting... are you sure that runs? For example, dequeue is not a "placeholder", so are you sure you can feed it?

Comment: Yes, it works fine (I tried it with TensorFlow 0.10.0rc1).  The point is that TensorFlow lets you feed the output of *any* operation, not just placeholders, and in this case it does not try to evaluate the operation.  In practice, people generally use placeholders to make their intent clear, so perhaps it's recommended to use placeholders instead, but I feel that in this particular case it is somewhat more natural to go for simplicity and forget about placeholders.

Comment: Wow thanks for this. My world view has changed slightly

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is to use the recently added (in TensorFlow 0.8) [`tf.placeholder_with_default()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder_with_default) op, which allows you to specify a default value (typically the output of the queue/reader), and also allows you to feed values that might have different shapes.

For example, let's say your queue produces batches of 32 elements, where each elements has 784 features, to give a 32 x 784 matrix.

```
input_from_queue = ...  # e.g. `queue.dequeue_many(32)` or `tf.train.batch(..., 32)`
# input_from_queue.get_shape() ==> (32, 784)

input = tf.placeholder_with_default(input_from_queue, shape=(None, 784))
# input.get_shape() ==> (?, 784)

# ...
train_op = ...

sess.run(train_op)  # Takes examples from `queue`.
sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={input: ...})  # Takes examples from `feed_dict`.
```

This allows you to feed in variable-sized batches or use an input reader, as desired.

Comment: Just curious: why is the placeholder necessary? Wouldn't you get the same result without it? Simply feed the output of the `input_from_queue` op when running `train_op`, and AFAIU TensorFlow will not pull from the queue, right?

Comment: The placeholder lets you feed different-sized batches into the computation. If the `input_from_queue` had a fixed batch size (though it might not) and you tried to feed a different-sized batch to that tensor, you would get an error.